# Why is "My wife appointment government official." fragment?

Tags: grammar

I found some warning message when I write some text in the MS-WORD.

> the warning message is that "My wife appointment government official." is fragment.

What does fragment mean? what am I supposed to do to revise this sentence?

Comment: Is the wife scheduled to meet with a government official?  If so, she **has an appointment with a government official**.  If she has been given a job as a government official, she **has an appointment as a government official**. As the answers say,  you need a verb, but you also need a preposition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely intended:

> [My wife](subject) --- [appointment](verb) --- [government official](object).

But "appointment" is a noun in standard English. So this parsing isn't possible. There is no verb in this expression, so Word calls it a "Fragment". Strictly this isn't correct. This isn't a fragment of a grammatical sentence. It is just not correct English.

As this isn't a grammatical form of English it is hard to know exactly what you mean. But possibly:

> My wife was appointed a government official
>   My wife appointed a government official
>   My wife's appointment as a government official was on Monday.

Answer (score 1):

MS Word throws an error if the sentence it feels is not complete. You should have at least a verb in the sentence to complete it. If the sentences are short or do not have any verb or the words are not in a proper order, MS Word will mark that as an error.

> My wife appointment government official

Frankly, I did not understand what you said there! Of course, a fragment issue. Where's a verb? Is there any possession? I'm not sure from the given context.

Anyway, if you want to get rid of 'fragment' problem from MS word, [here is the setting.](https://word.tips.net/T005665_Getting_Rid_of_Fragment_Warnings.html)